# Rename daframe column name

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a few column names in a data frame with special characters, and I would like to replace them.

For example, `df$Whole_2+_value` as `df$Whhole_2plus_value`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try `sub("\\+", "plus", names(df))`

Comment: As the answer by Darren Tsai might be incomprehensive to a newbie: the trick is that *names* can not only be used as a left value (read from) but alos as a right value (written to), e.g. `names(x) <- c("col1", "col2")`.

Comment: It would be helpful if you added an example dataframe along with expected output. We don't know which special characters you are talking about. Is it only `+` or there are some others like `-`. `/` etc. An example would have clear things up.

Comment: It's only '+'.        example dataframe is, df$Whole_2+_value and an expected answer is df$Whhole_2plus_value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to replace a name:

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    rename(Whhole_2plus_value = "Whole_2+_value")
```

If you want to replace each name one by one, you can separate them by commas: `rename(Whhole_2plus_value = "Whole_2+_value", ...)`
If there is a rule (like the commented by @Darren_Tsai), then:

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    rename_with(~sub("\\+", "plus", .), .cols = c("Whole_2+_value", ...))
```

where in place of `...` are the names of the other columns.

Comment: I'm facing the below error, Error : package or namespace load failed for ‘dplyr’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
 namespace ‘rlang’ 0.4.1 is already loaded, but >= 0.4.7 is required

Comment: You may try to exit `R` (or `RStudio`) and then try to install again last version of `rlang`?